# Mui Table Filter withour Data Grid Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am Using enhancedTable from mui material, you can reach its demo code from here https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#sorting-amp-selecting
I need to apply filtering to the columns but the native filtering only shown in the Data Grid component, I could'nt fight an example for enchanedTable version(which basically uses table,tableBody, tableHead etc.) I can't just swap to DataGrid at this point. Any idea how can I apply to filtering to all columns?

I tried to create a custom filtering with modal but its just too complicated and I don't have enough time for that.